# Windows Server 2003 / IIS : web site periodically drops off the net

Tags: networking, iis, web-server

My web server (windows server 2003 with IIS) has two network adapters, one that joins it to my local network, and another that connects it to the internet.

Periodically (once every 1-3 days) it stops serving pages over the internet.  Requests from the outside world are met with a "could not connect to host" type error.  DNS resolves to the right IP, and my connection to the internet has not been disrupted.  there's just no response to the request.  However IIS happily continues to serve up pages on the local network.  My only remedy for the problem so far has been a reboot.

I just discovered another way to fix the problem: if I open the Network Connections interface through the Control Panel, right click on the network adapter that is connected to the net, and hit "Repair", the problem will go away after the repair operation is done.  I think this is a major clue.

What causes a problem like this?  How could I fix it?

Thanks for your help, superusers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start by looking at :

1. the server log files to see if
   there are any network related
   issues.
2. Update network card driver (see if you can find a backup for the existing drivers first)
3. If you're able to track down the
   time that the server drops the
   connection, check out the logs on
   the router (internet side)  Talk to your isp if necessary.
4. Replace the offending network card
   if it happens again
5. If your internet router more than
   one port on it, try another port

Ak

Comment: Sorry about the delayed response.  This question got moved by an admin from superuser.com so I missed your answer.  I replaced the network card and everything is great.